# JavaScript Plotly unable to populate JSON object to bar graph in html

Tags: javascript, json, plotly.js

I currently have data from a JSON file that I am importing into my app.js file. I want to be able to plot a very simple bar graph but for some reason, the data isn't plotting at all.

My JSON file looks like this
`{"value": [44.0, 42.0, 41.0, 40.0, 38.0, 37.0, 36.0], "score": [1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 121]}`

Here is my code:

```
var value = [];
var score = [];

d3.json("../static/assets/js/data.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        value.push(data.value)
        
        console.log(value) // shown on console as [Array(7)]

        score.push(data.score)
        
        console.log(score) // shown on console as [Array(7)]
        
    })

console.log(value) //shows up on the console as []
                                             // 0: (7) [44, 42, 41, 40, 38, 37, 36]
                                             // length: 1
                                             // __proto__: Array(0)

console.log(score) //shows up on the console as []
                                             // 0: (7) [1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 121]
                                             // length: 1
                                             // __proto__: Array(0)

var trace = {
    x: value,
    y: score,
    type: "bar"
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace])
```

I'm not worried about aesthetics at the moment as I want to be able to plot the chart first.

When I console.log([trace]), I get

```
[{...}]
 0: {x: Array(1), y: Array(1), type: "bar"}
     type: "bar"
    x: [Array(7)]
       0 : (7) [44, 42, 41, 40, 38, 37, 36]
    y: [Array(7)]
       0 : (7) [1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 121]
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

when I know the result should be

```
[{...}]
 0: {x: Array(7), y: Array(7), type: "bar"}
     type: "bar"
    x: (7) [44, 42, 41, 40, 38, 37, 36]
    y: (7) [1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 121]
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I'm a little stuck as to what my error might be that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible erros in your code:

1. By using `value.push(data.value)` you are creating nested arrays. So instead of `[1,2,3]`, which you would achieve by writing `value = data.value`, your array is `[[1,2,3]]`.
2. `d3.json` is an asynchronous call, which means that your data will only safely be available once the callback function is called (`function(data) {}`). You should put the code which generates the chart into the callback function.

See the example below. I emulated `d3.json` with my `jsonRequest` function, you can ignore that part. By putting the plotly call into the callback function, you can omit the `value` and `score` arrays and just access `data.value` and `data.score` directly.

```js
const mockJson = {
  value: [44, 42, 41, 40, 38, 37, 36],
  score: [1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 121]
}

const jsonRequest = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(mockJson)
    }, 2000);
  });
}

jsonRequest().then(function(data) {        
    var trace = {
      x: data.value,
      y: data.score,
      type: "bar"
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace])        
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```